# html and css resposive website has abnormal styling

Tags: html, css, mobile-website

what is the problem? why the links is at not correct position?how can I keep the links in correct position after minimizing the browser also there is no separation between the links. why this happens?please rectify my css code. also how can I make it more resposive.

```css
.body {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  color: 000305;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  /*Base font size 14px*/
  font-family: arial, "Lucida Sans Unicode";
  font-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  clear: both;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #CF5C3F;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  color: #FFF;
}
.mainHeader img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 2% 0;
  border-radius: 90px;
}
.mainHeader nav {
  background-color: #666;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link,
.mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover,
.mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link,
.mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  height: 20px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainContent {
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.content {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
.topcontent {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.bottomcontent {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.top-sidebar {
  width: 21%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.middle-sidebar {
  width: 21%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.bottom-sidebar {
  width: 21%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.mainFooter {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #666;
  margin-top: 2% margin-bottom: 2%;
  height: 40%;
}
.mainFooter p {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 92%;
  color: #FFF;
}
.postinfo {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>HTML5/CSS3 responsive theme</title>
</head>
<!--Body start here!-->

<body class="body">

  <header class="mainHeader">
    <!--Main logo of the page!-->
    <img src="img/images.jpeg" alt="logo here">
    <!-- Main navigation bar!-->
    <nav>

      <ul>

        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</li>
    
    <li><a href="#">About </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">Portofolio </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">Contact </li>

    </ul>
    
    </nav>

</header>

<!--Main content starts here!-->

<div class="mainContent">
<div class="content">

<article class="topcontent">

<header> 
   <h2><a href="#" title="First post">First post</a>
          </h2>
  </header>

  <footer class="postinfo">
    <p>This post is written by Christian</p>
  </footer>

  <content>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada ac lacinia vel, vulputate sit amet arcu. Aliquam quis congue nulla. Nulla egestas nisl risus, accumsan
      iaculis sem scelerisque vel. Praesent sit amet risus efficitur, rhoncus nisi quis, tincidunt dui. Duis consequat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada ac lacinia vel, vulputate sit amet arcu. Aliquam quis congue nulla. Nulla egestas nisl risus, accumsan
      iaculis sem scelerisque vel. Praesent sit amet risus efficitur, rhoncus nisi quis, tincidunt dui. Duis consequat.</p>
  </content>


  </article>

  <!--bottom content starts!-->

  <article class="bottomcontent">

    <header>
      <h2><a href="#" title="Second post">Second post</a></h2> 
    </header>

    <footer class="postinfo">
      <p>This post is written by Christian</p>
    </footer>

    <content>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada ac lacinia vel, vulputate sit amet arcu. Aliquam quis congue nulla. Nulla egestas nisl risus, accumsan
        iaculis sem scelerisque vel. Praesent sit amet risus efficitur, rhoncus nisi quis, tincidunt dui. Duis consequat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada ac lacinia vel, vulputate sit amet arcu. Aliquam quis congue nulla. Nulla egestas nisl risus, accumsan
        iaculis sem scelerisque vel. Praesent sit amet risus efficitur, rhoncus nisi quis, tincidunt dui. Duis consequat.</p>
    </content>


  </article>


  </div>
  </div>
  <!--This is the right side content!-->
  <aside class="top-sidebar">
    <article>
      <h2>Top sidebar</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada</p>
    </article>
  </aside>

  <aside class="middle-sidebar">
    <article>
      <h2>Top sidebar</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada</p>
    </article>
  </aside>

  <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
    <article>
      <h2>Top sidebar</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada</p>
    </article>
  </aside>
  <!--This should be the foot of the webpage!-->
  <footer class="mainFooter">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 <a href="#" title="1stwebdesinger">1stwebdesinger.com</a>
    </p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: first close all a href tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some css and html issues in your code.
First close all `<a href>` tag and second remove `float:left` from `.mainHeader nav ul li` class and replace inline to inline-block so you won't need height to show  background of nav.

After that you will see all menus are in one row but after resizing little bit more, menu will go down as no such space. For this issue you have to use **Media query** to solve or use **bootstrap** or navbar menu style.

You can read more about [Media query](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) or [Bootstrap](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/) for responsiveness.

Check my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qrwLLqz/) here.

*** **Note** : Whenever you are using `float:left` then try to use `clear:both` after that so there won't be any extra white gap/space however I have removed float from your code, so just side note. Hope it will help..

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I got it.

Comment: My pleasure :) if it helps you then please accept as answer.. thanx

Answer (score 0):

Two problem what i have noticed in your code you are not closing the `<a>` tags

2nd setting the height on hover are never a good practice. on hover links height increases that's why such things happening. `see snippet`

**UPDATED CODE** TRY MEDIA QUERY

```
@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
 .mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
   font-size:80%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
/**MORE CODE FOR WIDTH 0 to 768px**/ 
    }
```

```css
.body {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  color: 000305;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  /*Base font size 14px*/
  font-family: arial, "Lucida Sans Unicode";
  font-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  clear: both;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #CF5C3F;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  color: #FFF;
}
.mainHeader img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 2% 0;
  border-radius: 90px;
}
.mainHeader nav {
  background-color: #666;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link,
.mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover,
.mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link,
.mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
 
  text-shadow: none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainContent {
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.content {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
.topcontent {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.bottomcontent {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.top-sidebar {
  width: 21%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.middle-sidebar {
  width: 21%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.bottom-sidebar {
  width: 21%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.mainFooter {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #666;
  margin-top: 2% margin-bottom: 2%;
  height: 40%;
}
.mainFooter p {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 92%;
  color: #FFF;
}
.postinfo {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 90%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 768px) {
 .mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
   font-size:80%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
} 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>HTML5/CSS3 responsive theme</title>
</head>
<!--Body start here!-->

<body class="body">

  <header class="mainHeader">
    <!--Main logo of the page!-->
    <img src="img/images.jpeg" alt="logo here">
    <!-- Main navigation bar!-->
    <nav>

      <ul>

        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    
    <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
    
    <li><a href="#">Portofolio </a></li>
    
    <li><a href="#">Contact </li>

    </ul>
    
    </nav>

</header>

<!--Main content starts here!-->

<div class="mainContent">
<div class="content">

<article class="topcontent">

<header> 
   <h2><a href="#" title="First post">First post</a>
          </h2>
  </header>

  <footer class="postinfo">
    <p>This post is written by Christian</p>
  </footer>

  <content>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada ac lacinia vel, vulputate sit amet arcu. Aliquam quis congue nulla. Nulla egestas nisl risus, accumsan
      iaculis sem scelerisque vel. Praesent sit amet risus efficitur, rhoncus nisi quis, tincidunt dui. Duis consequat.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada ac lacinia vel, vulputate sit amet arcu. Aliquam quis congue nulla. Nulla egestas nisl risus, accumsan
      iaculis sem scelerisque vel. Praesent sit amet risus efficitur, rhoncus nisi quis, tincidunt dui. Duis consequat.</p>
  </content>


  </article>

  <!--bottom content starts!-->

  <article class="bottomcontent">

    <header>
      <h2><a href="#" title="Second post">Second post</a></h2> 
    </header>

    <footer class="postinfo">
      <p>This post is written by Christian</p>
    </footer>

    <content>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada ac lacinia vel, vulputate sit amet arcu. Aliquam quis congue nulla. Nulla egestas nisl risus, accumsan
        iaculis sem scelerisque vel. Praesent sit amet risus efficitur, rhoncus nisi quis, tincidunt dui. Duis consequat.</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada ac lacinia vel, vulputate sit amet arcu. Aliquam quis congue nulla. Nulla egestas nisl risus, accumsan
        iaculis sem scelerisque vel. Praesent sit amet risus efficitur, rhoncus nisi quis, tincidunt dui. Duis consequat.</p>
    </content>


  </article>


  </div>
  </div>
  <!--This is the right side content!-->
  <aside class="top-sidebar">
    <article>
      <h2>Top sidebar</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada</p>
    </article>
  </aside>

  <aside class="middle-sidebar">
    <article>
      <h2>Top sidebar</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada</p>
    </article>
  </aside>

  <aside class="bottom-sidebar">
    <article>
      <h2>Top sidebar</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec aliquet interdum elit, id ultricies leo pretium id. Aenean erat risus, malesuada</p>
    </article>
  </aside>
  <!--This should be the foot of the webpage!-->
  <footer class="mainFooter">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2016 <a href="#" title="1stwebdesinger">1stwebdesinger.com</a>
    </p>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nav bar is still breakable after resizing the window..please update the code..thanx

Comment: code updated @Leothelion and i change code for 768px you can change that according to your convenience

Answer (score 0):

Changes in your style and html may it helps you

1- close your "a" tag

2- for repsponsive use style in

```
<style>
.body {
  background-color: #E8E8E8;
  color: 000305;
  font-size: 87.5%;
  /*Base font size 14px*/
  font-family: arial, "Lucida Sans Unicode";
  font-height: 1.5;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  clear: both;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #CF5C3F;
}
a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  color: #FFF;
}
.mainHeader img {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 2% 0;
  border-radius: 90px;
}
.mainHeader nav {
  background-color: #666;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link,
.mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
.mainHeader nav a:hover,
.mainHeader nav a:active,
.mainHeader nav .active a:link,
.mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  height: 20px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.mainContent {
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
.content {
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
}
.topcontent {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.bottomcontent {
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3% 5%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.top-sidebar {
  width: 21%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
.middle-sidebar {
  width: 21%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.bottom-sidebar {
  width: 21%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 3%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.mainFooter {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 5px;
  moz-border-radius: 5px;
  webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #666;
  margin-top: 2% margin-bottom: 2%;
  height: 40%;
}
.mainFooter p {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 92%;
  color: #FFF;
}
.postinfo {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 90%;
}
```

/*css for responsive */

```
@media (max-width:767px)
{
.mainHeader nav
{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li{
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    float:none;
}
.mainHeader nav, .mainHeader nav a:hover, .mainHeader nav a:active, .mainHeader nav .active a:link, .mainHeader nav .active a:visited{
    height:100%;
}
.mainHeader nav ul{
    padding:0px 0px;
}
.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited
{
width:100%;
}
.mainHeader nav ul li a{
    border-radius:0px 0px;
}
}
</style>


 <!--html-->


    <nav>

          <ul>

            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>

        <li><a href="#">Portofolio </a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Contact </li>

        </ul>

        </nav>
```

Comment: try to post css and html in different block and also point out that what main changes you did or needed to solve the answer so op can see without checking every line.. thanx